# A lot of people seem to be 'working for the man'. Who is this guy?

Tags: meaning, nuance

I have heard the expression 'working for the man' a lot. Mostly in podcasts made in the US.

What does that mean?

Does it express an opinion about the employer? Something along the lines of big, inhuman company?

Comment: Have you googled this?

Comment: The man even has [his own Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man). It's General Reference.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTAhKf91_SA got a lotta lotta lotta work to do...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's essentially correct. See [The Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man) for more.

> "The Man" is a slang phrase that may refer to the government or to some other authority in a position of power. In addition to this derogatory connotation, it may also serve as a term of respect and praise.
>
> The phrase "the Man is keeping me down" is commonly used to describe oppression. The phrase "stick it to the Man" encourages resistance to authority, and essentially means "fight back" or "resist", either passively, openly or via sabotage. (Wikipedia)

*Stick it to the man* is the idiom I'm most familiar with, but there are others. *Working for the man* in context might mean for a corporation, the government or other oppressive groups. *Save the Hammer for the Man* is a song title about oppression.

Comment: "Workin' for the man" was a huge hit song in I think '62. If you check the lyrics it gives lots of info.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_Orbison

Answer (score 1):

Working for the man:  (slang expression):

> - Usually refers to the "establishment", the boss, the white guy, white collar, government, etc., (Depends on who says it, but it's basically all of the above and more)
> - Performing a task, manual labor, or any type of assigned duty  for an  unappreciative, disrespectful person or organization for money.
>
>   Dude, are you still working for the man? Man, don't let the man get you down!

"The Man":

> - is a slang phrase that may refer to the government or to some other authority in a position of power. In addition to this derogatory connotation, it may also serve as a term of respect and praise.
>
> The phrase "the Man is keeping me down" is commonly used to describe oppression. The phrase "stick it to the Man" encourages resistance to authority, and essentially means "fight back" or "resist", either passively, openly or via sabotage.

Source: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man
Source:http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=working+for+the+man

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia, *[The Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man)* is

> a slang phrase that may refer to the government or to some other
>   authority in a position of power

so *working for the man* would mean working for the state or some large and powerful corporation. It usually carries with it the connotation that the speaker is being exploited or oppressed, or otherwise done down.

See also the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=The%20Man) (not always an unimpeachable source).