# "Work for the man" as Black English

Tags: african-american-vernacular-english

Is the phrase

***"work for the man"***

considered to be [African-American Vernacular English (AAVE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_English)  (also [Ebonics](https://www.linguisticsociety.org/content/what-ebonics-african-american-english))?

Comment: No, it's leftover hippie talk. *You da man* would be another thing.

Comment: Can you give any more details or context? I don't think it's possible to give an answer more definitive than "maybe" at present. (See definition 3 of [man](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/man)).

Comment: relevant: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188951/a-lot-of-people-seem-to-be-working-for-the-man-who-is-this-guy

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I have made some badly-needed edits to try and bring your post on-topic...consider taking this further by looking for an actual citation and source. Good luck...

Comment: @YosefBaskin ...not sure if Roy Orbison was a hippie. Gonna check that out.

Comment: See point 5 The Man- https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/2pq3qji

Comment: Now we have to fight over whether being AAVE makes a phrase exclusively so. Is this striped shirt blue? Yes, it's blue and white. I'm going with "Is X a Y thing?" to mean a Y thing alone, or we'll be here all day. Oh, I forgot, I already am.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - actually in Green’s Dictionary of Slang there are clear references to the usage of The  Man (the boss)  as US black, at least, originally.

Comment: @user66974 That is etymology of a single element ..I think the OP is asking if the phrase currently is considered AAVE. I am not sure we can answer that with any certainty...now that I am thinking on it, possibly there is a better question here....

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ - I think the OP is referring to the origin of the sentence which , as most expressions, has become widespread among people with time. But the origin is most likely US black

Comment: Also: 2000 [US] Ebonics Primer at www.dolemite.com  man, the Definition: 1. a working boss; the Caucasian male 2. a personification of white society, especially racially repressive white society [...] Example: The man is holdin me down.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ - I don't see any indication in the question that OP is asking about the origin of the phrase.

Answer (score 2):

***Coverage of 'the man' in general U.S. slang dictionaries***

Use of "the man" for a person or entity of great or unquestionable authority dates back to the early 1900s at least. J.E. Lighter, *Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang* (1997) offers the following relevant entry:

> **man** *n.* ... **3.** (often *cap.*) an authoritative or controlling person or (*later*) group.—constr[ued] with *the*. *Specif[ically]*:
>
> **a.** *Naut[ical] & Mil[itary]* a commanding officer or officer in charge. [First two cited occurrences:] **1918** in Battey *Sub[marine] Destroyer* 302: Anybody in {naval} authority is "the man." **1939** *A[merican] S[peech]* XIV 28: *Man: the,* n. The Officer in Charge or the Officer of the Day, when making an inspection. ...
>
> **b.** *Pris[on]* the warden of a prison. [First two cited occurrences:] **1918** in *A[merican] S[peech]* (Oct. 1933) 29: Another goddam word out o'you-all,an Ah'll send ev'ry goddam one of ye up t' the Man. **1942–49** Goldin et al. *D[ictionary of] A[merican] U[nderworld] L[ingo]* 135: *Man*....Prison keeper, warden, or other prison official. ...
>
> **c.** *Orig[inally' So[uthern] & Black E[nglish]* any man or group in a position of authority; authority as an abstract entity. [First two cited occurrences:] **1928** R. Fisher *Jericho* 306: *The man:* designation of abstract authority. He who trespasses where a sign forbids is asked: "Say, biggy, can't you read the man's sign?" **1929–32** in *A[merican] S[peech]* (Dec. 1934) 288: {Lincoln U[niversity]} *Man:* Anyone in authority. *When I rode in that exam I took the Man out!* means "When I cheated in that exam I put one over on the professor!"
>
> **d.** *Orig[inally] Und[erworld] & Black E[nglish]* a policeman, prison guard, or other law-enforcement officer.—also used collec[tively]. [First two cited occurrences:] **1930** G. Irwin *Tramp & Und[erworld] Slang*: *Man*.—A prison guard. **1933–35** D. Lamson A*bout to Die* 201: No, sir; if you're figurin' on startin' anything [illegal] at all, the first thing you do is...tell the Man all about it. Then everything will be all right, an' you don't have no trouble.
>
> **e.** *Narc[otics]* a drug dealer. [First two cited occurrences:] **1942** *A[merican] T[hesaurus of] S[lang]* 479: Narcotic trafficker....*hop merchant*,....*man*,....*peddler*. 1953 *OED S[upplement]*: When I first hit New Orleans, the main pusher—or "the Man," as they say there—was a character called Yellow. ...
>
> **f.** *Black E[nglish]* a man who is highly accomplished or respected; the best man in a given field or at a particular time. [First cited occurrence:] **1952** Mandel *Angry Strangers* 29: I'm diggin' a lot of Armstrong, 'cause he's the man. **1959** in R.S. Gold *Jazz Lexicon s.v. the man*: *The man*...Any cat deserving of great respect, musically or personally. ("Miles is the Man!"). ...
>
> **g.** *Black E[nglish]* white people collectively regarded as oppressors of blacks; (*hence*, in radical politics) the white ruling class or U.S. government; (*rarely*) a white person. [First two cited occurrences:] **1954** Killens *Youngblood* 22: How about going into the *man*'s army? **1964** *Newsweek* (Aug. 3) 16: It is time to let The Man know that if he does something to us, we are going to do something back. ...
>
> **h.** a boss; employer. [First cited occurrence:] 1959 A. Anderson *Lover Man* 129: I...decided that this kat at the head of the table was The Man. ...

This lengthy set of definitions treats all of the different meanings of "the man" as variations from a single point of origin. The most prominent shared meaning in these definitions seems to be, literally or figuratively,  "the man in charge, the man who wields power over others, the man who dominates the field."

Harold Wentworth & Stuart Flexner, *Dictionary of American Slang* (1960) offers a somewhat shorter entry for "the man":

> **Man, the** | **man, the** *n.* **1** The law; a law enforcement officer; a private detective. Fig[uratively], Uncle Sam; specif[ically], a federal law enforcement officer, as a U.S. treasury agent. 1957: "The drug trade's slang for a law enforcer was, indicatively, 'The Man.'" A. Halsey, *S[aturday] E[vening] P[ost]*, Mar. 30, 101. 2 The leader of a band, esp. a jazz band or combo. 1957: "The Man—The leader of a band." E. Horne, *For Cool Cats and Far-Out Chicks*. ...

---

***Coverage of 'the man' in Black English slang dictionaries***

Turning now to specifically African American usage of "the man", I note the following dictionary entries. From Clarence Major, *Dictionary of Afro-American Slang* (1970):

> **Man, the:** policeman, and white authority-figure; one's white boss.

From Geneva Smitherman, *Black Talk: Words and Phrases from the Hood to the Amen Corner* (1994):

> **The Man** (1) The police. Crossover term. Also *five-O* (newer term that has not crossed over). (2)A male of distinction. "Michael Jordan is The Man." (3) The white man.

Although Smitherman seems to regard "the man" in the sense of "the police" as originally an African-American term that crossed over into mainstream U.S. usage, Lighter takes a more cautious approach, dating the term in that sense to 1930 and listing it as "originally Underworld and Black English." Moreover, there seems to be a fairly direct line to to "the man" as "a policeman, prison guard, or other law-enforcement officer" and the earlier sense of "warden of a prison"—which is not identified as specifically Black English. And just as early as the first cited instance of the man in that sense is the first cited instance of "the man" in the sense of "a commanding officer or officer in charge" in a military or naval setting: both go back to 1918 at least, and Lighter attributes neither to Black English.

And from Stephen Calt, *Barrelhouse Words: A Blues Dialect Dictionary* (2009):

> **man, the (1)** *I'd rather be sloppy drunk, sitting in the can / Than to be out in the streets, runnin' from the man.* —Leroy Carr, "Sloppy Drunk Blues," 1930 | The police individually or collectively, a seeming black modification of the 19th-century slang phrase the man in blue {F[armer] & H[enley, *Slang & Its Analogues Past and Present*], 1896), which became general convict slang (*D[ictionary of] U[nderworld] L[ingo]*).
>
> **man, the (2)** *Tell you women, how to keep your husbands at home / Get you a job, an' roll for the man, an' try to carry your labor home.* —Blind Joe Reynolds, "Outside Woman Blues." 1930 | As used by blacks in the Jim Crow South, any white employer.

---

***'Work[ing] for the man' as a set phrase***

The earliest match for one or another form of "Work for the man" as a set phrase that I've been able to find in various database searches is from a song written and recorded in 1962 by Roy Orbison. Here are some of the lyrics to "[Workin' for the Man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ENNaP2ABbg)":

> Hey now you better listen to me every one of you / We got a lotta lotta lotta lotta work to do / Forget about your women and that water can / Today you're **working for the man** / Well, pick up your feet / We got a deadline to meet / I'm gonna see you make it on time / Now don't relax / I want elbows and backs / I wanna see everybody from behind / 'Cause you're **working for the man, working for the man** / Gotta make him a hand when you're **working for the man**

In a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_for_the_Man_(song)) about the song, Orbison explains the genesis of the song as follows:

> "I was working for El Paso Natural Gas in the daytime, cutting up steel and loading it onto trucks and chopping weeds and painting water towers. Our straw boss was Mr. Rose, and he wouldn’t cut me any slack."

Orbison's song doesn't seem to be infused with much proletarian solidarity, however. The singer notes that he has a budding romantic relationship with the daughter of the man who owns the company and that eventually he (the singer) is going to be "the man":

> Well, the boss man's daughter sneaks me water / Every time her daddy's down the line / She says "Meet me tonight, love me right / And everything is gonna be fine" / So I slave all day without much pay / I'm just biding my time / 'Cause the company and the daughter, you see / They're both gonna be all mine / Yeah, I'm gonna be the man, gonna be the man / Gotta make him a hand if you're gonna be the man

Also fairly early is the instance from "[Proud Mary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4482NFfZiA)," written by J.C. Fogerty of Creedence Clearwater Revival shortly after leaving the U.S. National Guard and recorded by that band in 1968. Here is the opening part of the song:

> Left a good job in the city / **Workin' for the man** every night and day / And I never lost one minute of sleepin' / Worrying 'bout the way things might have been / Big wheel keep on turning / Proud Mary keep on burnin' / Rollin', rollin', rollin' on the river

The earliest nonmusical instances of "work for the man" that I've found are from the late 1960s.

From Paul Good, [*The American Serfs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=s6-FAAAAIAAJ&q=%22workin%27+for+the+man%22&dq=%22workin%27+for+the+man%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQgpuhgfL4AhU1HzQIHdaWDRk4HhDoAXoECAMQAg) (1968) [combined snippets]:

> "How do we make ends meet?" he says, repeating a question. "They don't hardly meet. I lived in this house all the years I was **workin' for the Man** tenant an' hand. He never said nothin' about puttin' us off now that I can't work. So I don't say nothin' to him so long as he don't say nothin' to me."

From "[The Black Policeman Is a Man in the Middle](https://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=AUE19681206.2.30&e=-------en-20--1--img-txIN-%22workin%27+for+the+man%22---------)," in the *[Washington, D.C.] American [University] Eagle* (December 6, 1968):

> When SDS tried to disrupt Columbia University's registration last fall, a handful of Negro guards stood in the doorway of the registration building to keep the militants out.
>
> During the scuffle that ensued, a young black radical with an Afro haircut elbowed his way angrily through the crowd and confronted one of the black officers.
>
> "What you doin' here **workin' for The Man**," he shouted into the officer's face. "You set foot in Harlem, you're dead!"

From Charles Rice, "[Who's Using Whom?](https://thecatholicnewsarchive.org/cgi-bin/crra?a=d&d=TPC19690606-01.1.4&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22working+for+the+man%22-------)" in the *Pittsburgh [Pennsylvania] Catholic* (June 6, 1969):

> In the meantime he [Ed Marciniak] has been **working for the man**, for Mayor Richard Daley to be exact; in Daley’s pure hierarchy Marciniak has gone upward. Whether there is a connection between his upward mobility and his thoughts I am not prepared to say but they have not been in conflict.

From an [advertisement for J & D Marketing Research](https://books.google.com/books?id=w9oDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA144&dq=%22working+for+the+man%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwji0o7B__H4AhUZDkQIHUaBC1MQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22working%20for%20the%20man%22&f=false) in *Ebony* magazine (September 1969):

> "TIRED OF **WORKING FOR THE MAN**?" Big profits $$ are predicted in African Culture Imports. Cash $$ in on the fastest growing Black Industry across the country today.

From an [unscheduled speech](https://books.google.com/books?id=r8krAQAAMAAJ&q=%22working+for+the+man%22&dq=%22working+for+the+man%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwixnfmmyvL4AhXdHTQIHQbMAzU4ChDoAXoECAUQAg) given at the 1970 meeting of the American Association for the Advancement of Science, reprinted in *Science for the People*, volumes 2–6 (1970[?]):

> You still have the opportunity to work constructively with the movement for revolutionary change. There is still time to stop **working for the man** and start serving the people. But if scientists continue to provide the ruling class with more tools of oppression, people like us won't be standing here trying to communicate our ideas to you. Out of desperation and urgency, and because no other solution is available, we will be out in the streets, with all of those excluded from ruling-class privilege, doing everything we can to tear this racist, imperialist system to shreds.

And from Craig Bowman, "[The Individual Black Man](https://www.coloradohistoricnewspapers.org/cgi-bin/colorado?a=d&d=PPR19700413-01.2.10&e=-------en-20--1--img-txIN%7ctxCO%7ctxTA-%22works+for+the+man%22-------0------)," in the *[Denver, Colorado] Paper* (April 13, 1970):

> This last black phenomenon is of special interest to me; especially since I do not believe that any such creature ever really existed. But according to current definition, a "tom” is simply one who **works for the "man”**, he certainly doesn’t believe in power politics, violence; ...

---

***Conclusions***

Early (which is to say, late 1960s) instances of "work[ing] for the man" tend toward either of two meanings: "work[ing] for the established power structure" or "work[ing] for the white man." The former meaning seems to have emerged by the early 1960s in the context of workers of unspecified race viewed in relation to their bosses or others who had leverage over them, before becoming a trope in left-wing rhetoric of the late 1960s and 1970s. The latter meaning is unmistakably race-specific and may well have been in use long before the 1960. We see hints of it in the 1930 lyric by Blind Joe Reynolds, cited in *Barrelhouse Words*, advising women who want to keep their men at home to "Get you a job, an' roll for the man, an' try to carry your labor home."

Whether a phrase familiar to and used by a wide array of U.S. English speakers of various ethnicities and speech preferences is properly assignable to one particular category of English speech seems to me to be less a matter of objective reality and more a matter of arbitrary categorization. A specialist in AAVE might claim "work for the man" as, at root, an African American turn of phrase—but other U.S. domains (most notably military slang, prison slang, and ethnically undifferentiated Southern slang) might lay equally plausible claim to having introduced "the man" as a concrete or abstract reference to those in power.

About all that I can say with some degree of confidence is that "the man" appeared in at least five specific slang senses within a dozen years of its earliest cited occurrences in the *Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang*, some of them explicitly linked to Black English and others not.